# BPF design as cascaded second order biquads

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response, biquad

I am trying to design a bandpass filter in MATLAB with following specs:
$$\texttt{f_s = 20000Hz}$$
$$\texttt{3dB freq = [392 464]Hz}$$
$$\texttt{filter order = 8}$$

When I tried to implement the filter using inbuilt function :

```
   h  = fdesign.bandpass('N,F3dB1,F3dB2', N, Fc1, Fc2, Fs);
   Hd = design(h, 'butter');
```

I got the second order biquad filter coefficients as follows:

```
1   0   -1  1   -1.96987205062106   0.990718473985264
1   0   -1  1   -1.97676581609302   0.992045526683144
1   0   -1  1   -1.95973988650702   0.978659265852826
1   0   -1  1   -1.96334289961579   0.979977069966408
```

When I tried to implement using inbuilt functions `butter` and `tf2sos`,
I got the second order biquad filter coefficients as follows:

```
1   1.99999999234270    0.999999988450783   1   -1.95973523410046   0.978656597594067
1   -1.99999999488179   0.999999991001735   1   -1.96333486913308   0.979967161667152
1   2.00000000765730    1.00000001154921    1   -1.96987710103010   0.990723209564209
1   -2.00000000511822   1.00000000899827    1   -1.97677344857326   0.992053519934887
```

Why is it different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are mostly identical (except for some small numerical errors).

The SOS matrix is not a unique way to describe a filter. The same filter can be implemented with many different SOS matrices depending on zero/pole pairing, section scaling and section ordering. In fact, building a "good" SOS matrix is one of the more tricky parts of filter design.

In your case the main difference is in the zeros. The filter has 4 zeros at $z=1$ and another 4 zeros $z=-1$. The `dfilt.df2sos` object pairs one of each for each section resulting in a zero polynomial of $[1, 0, -1]$ for each.

`zp2sos` pairs  two poles at $z=1$ and two poles $z=-1$ which gives the polynomials of $[1, 2, 1]$ and $[ 1,-2, 1]$.

The rest is just section ordering. If you want to compare two filters, compare the poles and zeros. They are unique. Avoid transfer function representation `tf` or $[b,a]$ since it's numerically by far the worst.

Either version is a bad filter. The relative bandwidth is way too small for the filter order and you get something that hovers around -40dB.

Here is the code to verify that the filters are the same.

%

```
% Compare two filters

N = 8;
Fc1 = 392;
Fc2 = 464;
Fs = 20000;
h  = fdesign.bandpass('N,F3dB1,F3dB2', N, Fc1, Fc2, Fs);
Hd = design(h, 'butter');
sos1 = Hd.sosMatrix;

%% 
[z,p,k] = butter(N/2,[Fc1 Fc2]*2/Fs);
sos0 = zp2sos(z,p,k);

%% compare poles and zeros
[z0,p0,k0] = sos2zp(sos0);
[z1,p1,k1] = sos2zp(sos1);

% sort and compare
d = sort(z0)-sort(z1);
fprintf('Mean errors for zeros = %6.2g\n',rms(d));
d = sort(p0)-sort(p1);
fprintf('Mean errors for poles = %6.2g\n',rms(d));
```